# is not a function angular ionic

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I have below code in the angular component in the ionic app.
In .html=>

```
<ion-col *ngFor="let a of article; let i=index" size="4">
         <div (click)="openArticle()">
          <ion-thumbnail slot="start">
          <ion-img [src] ="a.src" > </ion-img>
          </ion-thumbnail>
          <ion-label class="article-title">{{a.title}}</ion-label>
         </div>
        </ion-col>
```

In .ts =>

```
openArticle(){
    console.log("test")
}
```

If I click on tab getting openArticle is not a function at. this function should show a console message.

Comment: Issue resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `tappable` to your div

`<div tappable (click)=“myFunction($event)”>`

Comment: Are you sure your function is inside the corresponding .ts controller file? It should not be in a different controller.!

Answer (score 0):

Try with below code

```
<ion-col *ngFor="let a of article; let i=index" size="4" tappable (click)="openArticle()">
     <ion-thumbnail slot="start">
          <ion-img [src] ="a.src" > </ion-img>
     </ion-thumbnail>
     <ion-label class="article-title">{{a.title}}</ion-label>
</ion-col>
```

Comment: this solution is not working getting the same error

Comment: you don't have to add tappable on ion-col

Answer (score 0):

Can you please make sure that the `openArticle()` function is inside the **component** that refers to the **.html page**?

Maybe it's inside the **.ts file** but not inside the **component class**.